# How to solve this integration $ \int_{0}^{\tau} e^{-|\Gamma-k/f|/\theta_1} d\Gamma $?

Tags: integration, problem-solving, absolute-value

I am trying to solve this expression.

$$ \int_{0}^{\tau} e^{-|\Gamma-k/f|/\theta_1} d\Gamma$$

$k,f,\theta_1$ are positive fixed variables.

Here, the is an absolute value of $\Gamma-k/f$. I tried to divide them in two parts and then I summed these two parts. But i failed. can any one help?

Comment: What is your variable of integration ? Can you give some detail about all the parameters ?

Comment: Ok, I edited  my qustion

Comment: your idea is correct, where is the problem?

Comment: @tired I want to know limitation parameters of the two integrations

Comment: @tired also, during the interval of $[0, \tau]$ the exponential gives me a positive value. so how can i represent the absolute?.

Comment: @Zubzub thank you very much. I used third term and it solve my proplem. 
$$
\int_0^{a} e^{\frac{\Gamma-a}{\theta}} d\Gamma + \int_a^\tau e^{\frac{a-\Gamma}{\theta}} d\Gamma
$$
However, I couldnot understtod why. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a:= k/f$ then :

if $a \geq \tau$ then $\Gamma -a \leq 0$ hence :
$$
\int_0^\tau e^{\frac{\Gamma-a}{\theta}} d\Gamma
$$
if $a \leq 0$ then $\Gamma -a \geq 0$  hence :
$$
\int_0^\tau e^{\frac{a-\Gamma}{\theta}} d\Gamma
$$
else 
$$
\int_0^{a} e^{\frac{\Gamma-a}{\theta}} d\Gamma + \int_a^\tau e^{\frac{a-\Gamma}{\theta}} d\Gamma
$$

Comment: thank you very much. I used third term and it solve my proplem. 
$$
\int_0^{a} e^{\frac{\Gamma-a}{\theta}} d\Gamma + \int_a^\tau e^{\frac{a-\Gamma}{\theta}} d\Gamma
$$
However, I couldnot understtod why. Can you explain?

Comment: You know that $\Gamma$ will vary between $[0,\tau]$. You then need to check whether the stuff within the absolute value will change sign on this interval and this depends on $a$. We have three cases, whether $a$ is before the interval, after the interval, or within. In each case we need to check is the stuff in the absolute value is positive or negative and change the sign of the stuff accordingly.

Comment: I got it. For the third case, Is $a$ within the interval of $[0,\tau]$?

Comment: Yep when we have $\Gamma \in [0,a]$, this makes the stuff in the abs-value negative. And when $\Gamma \in[a,\tau]$, the stuff is positive.